# Making beta version live

Tags: release, publish, beta

I have a game. At first, it was published as a beta version in the Play Store. Then we uploaded the release version, so the beta version was deactivated automatically. However, in the store, I see that the app has a "Beta" label in its name. What should I do to make the "Beta" label disappear from the game's name?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are a beta developer, the application will have the **"(Beta)"** suffix after the name.

However, if you check the application's page while being logged out, you will see that the suffix is **not visible** for the public.